# Discord Bot .addFields name and value dosn't work

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a title and more descriptions the problem is that "value" is not working. I can't even start the bot it gives me this error:

***ERROR***
{name: 'test' value: 'test'}
^^^^^(these are under "value")

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

***CODE***

```js
.addFields(
  {name: 'test' value: 'test'}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the comma between the 'test' and the value.

```js
.addFields(
  {name: 'test', value: 'test'}
)
```

Comment: no problem, everyone miss little pieces of code. If the answer solved your question, you can mark it as answered, so it's already closed.